# Как сделать иконку из картинки, лежащей в одной папке с проектом?

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь назначить иконку приложения. Подключил ее в ресурсном файле

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
<file>../TLeater.jpg</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

и вызвал в main.cpp

```
  w.setWindowIcon(QIcon("../TLeater.jpg"));
```

Выдает ошибку ресурсного файла. Как правильно обратиься к картинке, если она лежит в той же папке, что и весь проект? Если я правильно помню, к файлам, которые лежат в той же папке обращаются через `../` в с++

Полный путь к файлу работает

P.S исправил `../` на `./` в обоих файлах, но картика все равно не появляется.

Comment: К файлам в той же папке обращаются через `./filename` или просто по имени файла, а `..` означает каталог на уровень вверх.... а по поводу самой задачи, не проще ли это сделать через редактор ресурсов и дизайнер?

Comment: Исправил, но иконка все равно не появляется

Comment: Проще, но нельзя по условию задачи

Comment: возможно, нужно писать `qrc:///<имя файла>` (например `qrc:///../TLeater.jpg`) или в RCC файле указывать alias'ы для файлов, чтобы по alias их получать. Пример файла в ресурсе: https://github.com/gil9red/PeriodicTableMendeleev/blob/833b31d5456037e786827369be29e8555f754eaa/resource.qrc#L3 и то как в коде его получаем: https://github.com/gil9red/PeriodicTableMendeleev/blob/833b31d5456037e786827369be29e8555f754eaa/main.cpp#L47

Comment: `QIcon(":/TLeater.jpg")`, см. [документацию](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#using-resources-in-the-application). и использовать jpeg в качестве иконки — не самая лучшая идея...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ из коментариев:

```
QIcon(":/TLeater.jpg")
```

работает. Пошел читать [документацию](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#using-resources-in-the-application)

Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Создал пустой проект, добавил файл ресурсов.

Первое, на что обратил внимание при добавлении файла ресурсов из Qt Creator, **обязательное** наличие префикса перед иконками (иначе попросту нельзя было добавить файлы, см. скриншот). Не могу объяснить, почему это так. Если кто-то просветит, то только приветствуется.

[image: неактивный пункт добавления файлов без префикса]

Затем добавил иконку в ресурсы и через дизайнер установил эту иконку в тайтл окна. Нажал "запустить". Удостоверился, что иконка подключилась правильно.

Глянул файл ресурсов в текстовом редакторе, получил такое:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/icons">
        <file>edit-icon.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Далее открыл файл *ui_mainwindow.h* (сгенерированный при сборке, лежит в папке с билдом) и поиском по ключевому слову "icon" нашел следующие строки:

```
QIcon icon;
icon.addFile(QStringLiteral(":/icons/edit-icon.png"), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
MainWindow->setWindowIcon(icon);
```

Что из этого мы видим?

1. Как правильно заполнить файл ресурсов (с учетом префикса).
2. Как правильно обратиться к файлу из ресурсов (опять же с учетом префиска `":/icons/edit-icon.png"`).

Затем, имея готовый файл ресурсов и зная, как обратиться к иконке из ресурсов, очистил поле `windowIcon` в дизайнере, открыл mainwindow.cpp и в конструкторе вписал:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/icons/edit-icon.png"));
}
```

В итоге все работает.